# Can't calculate g(x) as Derivative(f(x))

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, datalore

**Hello!**

#### Problem: I can calculate `xp(t)` and `xh(t)` for any given `t` value, but not for `ġ(t)`.

##### Context:

I'm calculating a general solution for a vibration system, using the Duhamel's integral.
The result is a sum of 2 functions.

`xg(t) = xp(t) + xh(t)`

I'm also using *Jet Brain's* **Datalore** to quickly evaluate the results.

###### Lib:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi, linspace
import sympy as smp
from sympy import sin, cos, tan, exp, symbols, Derivative, integrate, Integral, Function
from sympy.solvers.solveset import linsolve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

###### My constants:

```
k = 100*10**3   #[N/m] - Rigidity
m = 10000       #[Kg] - Mass
c = 20*10**3    #[N.s/m] - Damping
f0 = 5000       #[N] - Initial force
x0 = -0.05      #[m] - Initial position
v0 = 0.2        #[m/s] - Initial velocity
```

###### Main variables:

```
wn = float(np.sqrt(k/m))   #[rad/s]
zeta = float(c/(2*m*wn))    
wd = wn*np.sqrt(1-zeta**2)
t0 = 2*pi/wn/2             #[s]
t1 = 5*2*pi/wn/2           #[s]
sloap = f0/t0
```

##### What I can do:

I can create a function `xh(t)`, insert a `t` value and obtain a valid result (using my **ti-nspire cx CAS** to check):

```
A, phi = symbols('A phi', real=True)
t = symbols('t', real=True, positive=True)

def xh(t):
    return A * exp(-zeta*wn*t)*sin(wd*t+phi)
```

I can do the same for `xp(t)`:

```
x = symbols('x', real=True, positive=True)
xp_integral = (f0/t0) * x * exp(-zeta*wn*(t-x)) * sin(wd*(t-x))

def xp(t):
    return 1/(m*wd) * integrate(xp_integral, (x, 0, t)).simplify()
```

And even for `xg(t)`:

```
def xg(t):
    return xh(t) + xp(t)
```

##### Where the trouble begins:

Now I need to solve a system of 2 equations, where I can get the values for `A` and `phi`.

`xg(t=0) = x0`  ← Normal function, for `t=0` the result is the initial position **[m]**.

`ẋg(t=0) = v0`  ← Derivative of `xg(t)`, for `t=0` the result is the initial velocity **[m/s]**.

But I can't get the derivative of `xg(t)` to produce any value:

```
a, phi = symbols('a phi', real=True)

def d_xg(t):
    return Derivative(xg(t),t, evaluate=True)
```

No mater the `t` value I throw in `d_xg(t)`, it will always give me the same expression.

Any help is welcome,
**Thanks!**

#Edit_01: changed `def d_xg(t)` to the current state.

Comment: Of course `d_xg(b)` will return the same expression: `b` is not used anywhere...

Comment: Yes, you are right, I should've changed back before posting.
It's the same if I switch the ```b``` for ```t```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `d_xg(t)` you are computing the symbolic derivative of `xg` with respect to `t`. If you call `d_xg(t)` multiple times you will always get the same expression because you are doing the same computation over and over again. Similarly, if you call `d_xg(A)`, you will compute the derivative of `xg` with respect to `A`.

Once you have computed `d_xg(t)`, you want to substitute `t=0` into that expression:

```
d_xg_at_t_0 = d_xg(t).subs(t, 0)
```

Comment: That's exactly it! Between posting and your answer, I did figure it out. Should try more before asking :D
Thank you!